# Pulling Data from Word Form

Tags: c#, ms-office, text-extraction

Using C#, I need to pull data from a word document. I have NetOffice for word installed in the project. The data is in two parts.

First, I need to pull data from the document settings.

Second, I need to pull the content of controls in the document.  The content of the fields includes checkboxes, a date, and a few paragraphs.  The input method is via controls, so there must be some way to interact with the controls via the api, but I don't know how to do that.

right now, I've got the following code to pull the flat text from the document:

```
private static string wordDocument2String(string file)
    {
        NetOffice.WordApi.Application wordApplication = new NetOffice.WordApi.Application();
        NetOffice.WordApi.Document newDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(file);
        string txt = newDocument.Content.Text;
        wordApplication.Quit();
        wordApplication.Dispose();
        return txt;
    }
```

So the question is: how do I pull the data from the controls from the document, and how do I pull the document settings (such as the title, author, etc. as seen from word), using either NetOffice, or some other package?

Comment: here is a starting point that may be of use: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518275/c-sharp-retrieve-formfields-from-word-document-and-insert-into-text-file).  By "document settings", do you mean properties like margins, font, line spacing, etc?  Those are pretty easy to get.  BTW, according to NetOffice docs, the api methods are exactly the same as Office Interop methods, which should help your googling a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I did not bother to implement NetOffice, but the commands should mostly be the same (except probably for implementation and disposal methods).

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        string file = "C:\\Hello World.docx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(file);

        // look for a specific type of Field (there are about 200 to choose from).
        foreach (Field f in doc.Fields)
        {
            if (f.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldDate)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }

        // example of the myriad properties that could be associated with "document settings"
        WdProtectionType protType = doc.ProtectionType;
        if (protType.Equals(WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyComments))
        {
            //do something else
        }
```

The [MSDN reference on Word Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.document_members.aspx) is where you will find information on just about anything you need access to in a Word document.

UPDATE:
After reading your comment, here are a few document settings you can access:

```
        string author = doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Author").Value;
        string name = doc.Name; // this gives you the file name.
                 //  not clear what you mean by "title"
```

As far as trying to understand what text you are getting from a "legacy control", I need more information as to exactly what kind of control you are extracting from.  Try getting a name of the control/textbox/form/etc from within the document itself and then look up that property on the Google.

As a stab in the dark, here is an (incomplete) example of getting text from textboxes in the document:

```
        List<string> textBoxText = new List<string>();
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape s in doc.Shapes)
        {
            textBoxText.Add(s.TextFrame.TextRange.Text); //this could result in an error if there are shapes that don't contain text.
        }
```

Another possibility is Content Controls, of which there are several types.  They are often used to gather user input.

Here is some code to catch a rich text Content Control:

```
        List<string> contentControlText = new List<string>();
        foreach(ContentControl CC in doc.ContentControls)
        {
            if (CC.Type == WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText)
            {
                contentControlText.Add(CC.Range.Text);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill just switch to interop

Comment: I think there is overlap in the definition of fields...i meant fields in the lay sense.  Changed it to controls.  This is actually tricky to transcribe since fields, controls and forms are already part of the system. So there are questions in the documents prompting the user to click on a box and input a response.  I need to pull, from the document, using code, the response to the question.  The response is in what seems to be something called a "legacy control."  Also, I need to pull the settings from the document wherein author, title, and other data is oriented.